# Mongodb atlas X509 auth doesn't work in transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a strange problem with Mongo Atlas using X509 certificate.
I have no problem connecting to Mongo Atlas usign X509 certificate, however, when I try to use it with a transaction I get the an error that the user is not authenticated.
This is my code:

```
    const mongoOptions = {
        authSource: "$external",
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        sslCert: credentials,
        sslKey: credentials,
        authMechanism: "MONGODB-X509"
    };
    const mongo = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI, mongoOptions);
    const connection = await mongo.connect();
    const session = mongo.startSession();
    const db = mongo.db(`configs_${configPrefix}`, {});
    try {
        await session.startTransaction();
        await db.collection(collection).updateOne({_id: id}, {$set: jsonData}, {upsert: true, session});
        await session.commitTransaction();
    } catch (e) {
        await session.abortTransaction();
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
        await connection.close();
    }
```

If I remove the session in the updateOne it works, if I add the session it throws the error.

If I'm using a username and password it works in all cases.

Is there any limitation or steps that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion and investigation with the atlas support. They confirmed it’s a bug in their shared clusters (M0, M2,M5). I can confirm that it’s not happening in M10+.

Comment: can you find the source for this info and link it here?

Comment: Also serverless "fixes this".

[...]Serverless instances do support X.509 certificates and IAM for authentication.[...]

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/

Comment: @ricricucit, the source is an internal correspondence with a MongoDB Atlas employee.

Comment: BTW I can confirm that this is no longer an issue, I was doing something else wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable command monitoring on the client, log all commands, observe that each command includes the connection id. Verify that the connections used for commands under transactions have previously authenticated.

Enable query logging on the server and repeat the analysis on the server, verify each connection that does crud has previously authenticated.